# create custom fltk dialog / modal window

Tags: fltk

I want to create a custom dialog window with fltk. I will put the widgets. Background process should wait to the dialog's finish. I couldn't find any example for this. I am looking fl_input function. I found makeform() function but it didn't help very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found innate() function in the library. In the function there is a line following:

```
while (w->shown()) Fl::wait();
```

this is my solution. For example:

```
Fl_Window* w = new Fl_Window(400, 300);
w->set_modal();
w->show();
while (w->shown()) Fl::wait();
```

will wait the user to close the window.

Answer (score 1):

Just use Fl_Window and call **set_modal()** function.